# Fit to Screen device metrics in Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the new version of Chrome 32.0.1700.77, the DevTools has now relocated user agent and device metrics to the new Emulation drawer.  My issue with it is that the Screen tab does not have a "Fit to Screen" option that it used to have.

That option used to maximize the viewport of the device on the screen while preserving the aspect ratio, regardless of screen size.  Is there any way to access this option or do something with the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you choose any device from the device list the "Fit to screen" option appears under the percentage select box.

If you don't want to choose any device (e.g use the `Responsive` option), first define your resolution and then scale it to your desire from the percentage select box.